# How to implement jquery datatable in asp.net core 2.1 application using nuget pakage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am create one application in asp.net core 2.1 and install nuget package `jquery.datatables` is successfully install in my machine but any javascript and css not add in my `wwwroot`

how to use jquery datatable in my application without use **cdn**

Comment: please check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/35140517/3734638